# Select option data-bind value with knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

Hi I have a observable array return from a web API.

1) How to I bind the return jSon as follows to the view model and how do I access it in view? 
 
2) Since there is no information about which option is selected from the returned jSon, how do I make the view initially display the selected option based on the `self.selectedAnimal` (which is the selected text)?

```js
function NewViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.selectedAnimal = "Cat";
  
  self.GetAnimal() {
    $.ajax({
      url:"http:/abc.com/api/GetAnimalList",
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      data: {}
      success: function() {
         // What to assign here
      }
    });
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new NewViewModel());

// example of json return
 "animals": [
    {
        "animalid": "1",
        "animalname": "cat" },
    {
        "animalid": "two",
        "animalname": "dog" },
    {
        "animalid": "three",
        "animalname": "horse"}
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `observableArrays`. Like this:

```
function NewViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.selectedAnimal = ko.observable('Cat');
  self.animals = ko.observableArray();

  self.getAnimals = function() {
    $.ajax({
      url:"http:/abc.com/api/GetAnimalList",
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      data: { }
      success: function(animals) {
         self.animals(animals);
      }
    });
  };

  //reload the animals 

  //load the view
  self.getAnimal();
}
```

In your view:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: animals">
   <label data-bind="text:animalname"></label> 
</div>
```

Fiddle with example https://jsfiddle.net/vnoqrgxj/

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
<select data-bind="options: animalOptions,
                       optionsText: 'animalname',
                       optionsValue: 'animalid',
                       value: selectedAnimal,
                       optionsCaption: 'Select animal'">
</select>
```

As select markup in HTML, then in your view model add the `animalOptions` array and fill that when the ajax request returns success.

```
function NewViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.selectedAnimal = "two"; // initial selection as 'dog'
  self.animalOptions = ko.observableArray([]);

  function GetAnimal() {
    $.ajax({
      url:"http:/abc.com/api/GetAnimalList",
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      data: {},
      success: function(data) {
         // What to assign here

          $.each(data.animals, function(i,option){
              self.animalOptions.push(option);
          });
      }
    });
  }

  GetAnimal();
}
ko.applyBindings(new NewViewModel());
```

For the initially selected option, set `self.selectedAnimal = "two"` i.e. the `animalid` value of desired selection.

Read [this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) for more information about options binding.